# Javascript onchange regex / character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an onchange within an input. However the regex pattern is not getting created correctly.

```
jQuery(this).attr("onchange", " 
var cat = jQuery('.coverage'); 
var dog = 0; 
for(var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++){ 
 if(cat[i].value){ 
  dog = parseInt(cat[i].value.replace(/\,/g,''), 10) + dog;
 } 
} 
var pat = new RegExp('\\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' , 'g');   
jQuery('#total').val(dog); ");
```

the pattern instead of being:

```
/\B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g
```

come out:

```
/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g
```

Note the onchange attr in this context is necessary sadly...

Comment: *Note the onchange attr in this context is necessary* - I find that very hard to believe. Anyway, you shouldn't be able to declare a string like that on multiple lines without escaping it. You should have got a syntax error.

Comment: Put one more \ => "\\\B" instead of "\\B" By the way I would attach the handler with `on()` method

Comment: by `"\d"` you mean "d" or the digit class `\d` (`[1-9]`) ?
In second case you have to double the slashes: `\\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the `onchange` attribute is **absolutely necessary** (I really do not see why it would be) you can still encapsulate the whole logic in a function and use it in the inline handler (it's still more elegant than a huge string).

```
//must be global, strongly consider namespacing
function onChange(e) {
    //do something

    //also all \ must be escaped in a string to put an actual \
    var pat = new RegExp('\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))', 'g');

    //but your pattern is not even dynamic so you should use a
    //regex literal instead of the RegExp constructor.

    pat = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
}

jQuery(this).attr("onchange", "onChange(event);");
```

However I really do not see why [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) wouldn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

you have use a real function instead of onchange string attribute, and I have changed

`var pat = new RegExp('\\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' , 'g');`

to

`var pat = new RegExp('\\\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' , 'g');`:

check this out it should work:

```
jQuery(this).change(function(){ 
    var cat = jQuery('.coverage'); 
    var dog = 0; 
    for(var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++){ 
        if(cat[i].value){ 
        dog = parseInt(cat[i].value.replace(/\,/g,''), 10) + dog; 
        } 
    } 
    var pat = new RegExp('\\\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' , 'g'); 
    jQuery('#tivcalc').val(dog); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep using `attr` you can do:

```
function run_onchange(e, elem){
    var cat = jQuery('.coverage');
    var dog = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++){
        if(cat[i].value){
            dog = parseInt(cat[i].value.replace(/\,/g,''), 10) + dog;
        }
    }
    var pat = new RegExp('\\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))' , 'g');
    jQuery('#total').val(dog);
}

jQuery(this).attr( "onchange", "run_onchange(event,this);" );
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/OvULUyO/3/edit).